# NSNotification called after viewDidLoad of next Controller

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have a landing menu page with two buttons.
After user clicks on one of them there is a post `Notification` to the next screen.
The `Notification` points to a method which I expect to load before `viewDidload`. 
However, the `viewDidload` in the next controller is done before the function of the Notification.
 Only If I include my code in `viewDidappear', I can make it work.
However, I don't want to call it each time the view appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer ViewController's `view` in your method or before to send the notification, ViewController's `view` will be created and will be called `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the method which the notification points to from the viewDidLoad instead of calling it directly. That may do the trick... If loading that VC is linked to the notification event.

When a VC is instantiated it will call viewDidLoad at top of its life cycle, it's a pretty early call.

Also, check the awakeFromNib: method.

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and
>   action connections already established.